# Is it possible to store a struct into a linked list?

Tags: c, struct, stack, maze

I'm writing a program that solves a maze using DFS algorithm and stack. I was thinking of storing the coordinates of the path used to get to the end onto a struct containing integers `x`,`y` for coordinates and then pushing that struct onto a stack to perform other instructions on (print, pop, etc.).

I have searched all over and have yet to find anything that helps. So I went ahead and set it up but I'm getting an error about type compatibility since I have my node data as an int but I'm trying to put in a struct. Being new to linked lists I have only seen data as an int or char. Finally, is it even possible to do what I want? If not could you suggest a way of passing both `x`,`y` coordinates onto the stack? Thank you in advance.

Here's a sample of my code, where to save space `a1` is an instance of `COORD`, and list is initialized as well as the maze and such.

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;           /* Value or data stored in node*/
    struct node *pNext; /* Reference to the next node address */
} NODE;

/*Structure declares pointers for front and back of the list*/
    typedef struct LIST {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
} LIST;

/* Structure to pass multiple values onto stack */
typedef struct COORD{
    int x;
    int y;
}COORD;

/*Example of one of the functions */
void lst_push_front(LIST *l, COORD *a1) {
    NODE *p = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    p->data = a1;
    p->pNext = l->front;

    l->front = p;
    if(l->back == NULL)   // was empty, now one elem
       l->back = p;
}
```

Comment: Change `int data` to `COORD data`, and `p->data = a1` to `p->data = *a1`.

Comment: ... or make `int data` a `void *data` instead for a generic approach ... in your `pull` function you'd explicitly have to cast `(COORD *)(p->data)` then though to get back to the correct pointer type ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code below.

Since COORD is a structure you can include it in another structure as shown in the below code.

Also make sure that the ordering of the structures are proper.
`p->data.x` is the right way to access the members of the structure `COORD`

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Structure to pass multiple values onto stack */
typedef struct COORD{
    int x;
    int y;
}COORD;

 typedef struct node {
    COORD data;           /*  --> Changes done here */
    struct node *pNext; /* Reference to the next node address */
} NODE;

/*Structure declares pointers for front and back of the list*/
    typedef struct LIST {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
} LIST;


void func(COORD *q)
{
    NODE *p = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    p->data.x = q->x;
    p->data.y = q->y;

    printf("%d %d",p->data.x,p->data.y);
    free(p);
}

int main(void) {

    COORD *q = malloc(sizeof(COORD));
    q->x = 20;
    q->y = 30;
    func(q);
    free(q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, by declaring data as `COORD`, I can use it as if it was an instance of that struct?

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not very informative. Please explain what the code you're showing does, why you chose to write it that way, and how you expect it to work.

Comment: Note that `COORD` has to be defined before `NODE` — the code shown won't compile unless the structure definitions are reordered.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh!! by the time i came back lot of things have happened .. I was actually writing the edited code

Answer (score 0):

As @barak manos mentions you should put `COORD` struct before `NODE` and change `int data` to `COORD data` and use `p->data = *a1`